# Multi element JSON object from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a Javascript JSON object

```
const student = { name: "bob", age: 7, grade: 6 }
```

and I can pass it to my Web API using axios POST command by

```
JSON.stringify(student)
```

and I can build my student object by looping an array and passing in a value such as

```
let studentArr= []
const student = { name: studentArr[i]["name"], age: studentArr[i]["age"], grade: studentArr[i]["grade"}
```

I'm using `i` in the example as the index because it could have 100 students.  As long as I pass in only one value for `i`, everything works fine.  My question is how can I make it into a multi-element JSON object from my array.  I've been spoiled by Newtonsoft.Json where I can pull data from a SQL database and create a JSON object.  If I just `JSON.stringify(studentARR)` is shows empty. I want to pass to the Web API all of the students on one post so the Web API can make a document and download it back.

I seen many different ways of trying to accomplish this and the methods seem to change over time. Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you check `studentARR` before calling `JSON.stringify`? `JSON.stringify` should work for arrays too

Comment: Yes Sir-- it shows up as an empty object [],[],[]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to `JSON.stringify` if you are using `axios`. The declaration of `axios.post` accepts `URL` as first parameter and the data which is `formdata` or the `JSON` object as second parameter

I'm pretty sure that you might not need to use `JSON.stringify` if you are using axios to post to a Web API

Example of using Axios post method https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example

Comment: I took it out and the web service gets a Blank []-- The example is very close to what I do for the one object-- one student. I don't have a problem with one  The issues is joining 100. Building a string or object